# Django raises 404 error during HttpResponseRedirect but after refreshing, shows the current page

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I have a page called 'Read Later' where the users read later posts are stored. I have the Read Later on the nav bar. Now, when the user has no read later posts and clicks on Read Later, the user is redirected back to the original page. I have a function based def for Read Later.

**views.py :**

```
def show_readlater(request, *args):
    global redirect
    global redirect_lock
    global return_address
    if not(redirect_lock):
        redirect = None
    else:
        redirect_lock = False
    if not(request.user.is_authenticated()):
        raise PermissionDenied
    else:
        user_instance = User.objects.get(username = request.user.username)
        userprofile_instance = UserProfile.objects.get(user = user_instance)
        readlater_objects = ReadLaterList.objects.all()
        readlater_list = []
        count = 0
        for x in readlater_objects:
            if x.username == request.user.username:
                readlater_post = Post.objects.get(slug = x.slug)
                readlater_list.append(readlater_post)
                count = count + 1
        if count == 0 :
            redirect = "no_readlater"
            redirect_lock = True
            return HttpResponseRedirect(return_address)   # The user is redirect back to the original page
        post_title = "Read Later" 
        template = "posts/show_posts.html"
        dictionary = {
            "total_posts"    : readlater_list,
            "title"          : post_title,
            "count"         : count,
            "redirect"      : redirect,

        }
        return render(request, template, dictionary)
```

Here, `redirect` is to display a message that no Read Later posts are there, in the original page.

The issue is that, when the redirect happens, Django says page not found, but upon refresh the page is loaded.

*What is happening ?*

Comment: You can't use global variables like this in Django, it will cause race conditions.

Comment: How do I get back to the original page with a message then?

Comment: You use the session.

Comment: Oh okay.. I will try that. That should help !

Comment: @KlausD: The task got easier and cleaner with sessions. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all change this

```
    global redirect
    global redirect_lock
    global return_address
```

to

```
request.session['redirect']= redirect
```

for all global variables

and use `redirect` instead `HttpResponseRedirect`

Comment: The 404error was because I was blocking certain redirects. I hadn't noticed it. But using sessions made it a very easy task. Thanks ! Btw, Is there any init method to initialise the sessions before loading any page in the website ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the url specified in the global variable "return_address" is correct and specified in your app/urls.py.

Comment: I have a similar function for search, and it works well redirecting properly.